# How to click back button programatically in IWizardPage in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin, I want to create a wizard for my new project type. I created pages by classes extends org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage. My requirement is, based on some condition in one page, I need to go back to previous page without pressing back button on page(programmatically).

Is it possible?

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea. The user will be confused by doing this. I would disable the finish and the next button and give an error, telling the user that he has to go back to the first page.

If you want to reuse some UI from the first page, define the UI as a new class and reuse it.

Comment: The requirement is, based on current page values, the next page does some lengthy operations, so we tried to run those lengthy operations in separate thread using IRunnableWithProgress. Clicking on next(in current page) button, these lengthy operation is seen as process bar in this current page itself and loading the next page after this operation, but when we get any error, it navigates to next page and showing the error.

Comment: So we need help here: 1. It is OK if we can capture nextbutton pressed(in WizardPage) event in the current page or 2. We need to destroy the next page and move back to previous page. 3. Is it possible to extend WizardDialog to my class along with WizardPage? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you give a Dialog error message, without creating this WizardPage? That would be simple and intuitive.. On the first page the user clicks next, then you wait for the Operation to be executed. If the operation fails, canFlipToNextPage must return false in order to stay on the same page and give an error back...

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar using the WizardDialog:showPage() method:

MyWizard.java

```
public void createPageControls(Composite pageContainer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.createPageControls(pageContainer);
    wizardDialog = (WizardDialog) getContainer();
}

public void skipProcessPage() {
    wizardDialog.showPage(workPage == arisDbPage ? focusPage : arisDbPage);
}

public void setWorkPage(IWizardPage workPage) {
    this.workPage = workPage;
}
```

here the processPage does the lengthy db lookup!

HTH thomas